# Why my Drop down list is not getting binded upon button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

i am trying to rebind my Dropdown upon button click, in particular if Block but it doesn't rebind, i mean that it should reload the drop down, kinda refresh and first item should be selected, i am doing this but not getting rebinded

Code:(It si inside buttong click event)

```
 if (NotAssignedConductors.Length > 0)
            {
                string[] NotAssignedConductorsArray = NotAssignedConductors.Split(':');

                foreach (string str in NotAssignedConductorsArray)
                {

                    ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes(str, ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);

                }
                FillDropDownListDevices();


            }
```

Method being called:

```
public void FillDropDownListDevices()
    {
        DropDownListDevices.DataSource = ManageTransport.ManageConductorDevices.GetDevices();
        DropDownListDevices.DataTextField = "TerminalSNO";
        DropDownListDevices.DataValueField = "DeviceID";
        DropDownListDevices.DataBind();
        DropDownListDevices.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("None", "-1"));
    }
```

Button:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListDevices" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListDevices_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="form-control">
    </asp:DropDownList>
  <ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCreate" EventName="click" />
        </Triggers>
</asp:updatePanel>
```

Comment: What about `CheckBoxLists`? Are they bind correctly? If so, please post your `FillDropDownListDevices()` method code here.

Comment: check now its updated

Comment: Are you using update panel ?

Comment: yes button is indise update panel @AnantDabhi

Comment: check the updates, i have updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are many possibilities**

1. If you are using update panel make sure you trigger update-panel to update on button click
2. check your page_load/page_loadComplete event and make sure you are not binding drop-down again .
3. check your browser console it throws any error on button click?

Create Post back trigger on update panel

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListDevices" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListDevices_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="form-control">
    </asp:DropDownList>
  <ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
     </Triggers>
</asp:updatePanel>
```

**Put your first time binding method on Postback**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (!IsPostBack) 
         {
             //means no postback..page loaded first time
             // Put your first time Binding method here 

         }
     }
```

Comment: 2. I am binding my drop down on page load post back also